# What Java class can be used to calculate runtime?

Tags: java, sorting, time, runtime

I'm trying to write a java program that generates a million random numbers, and then use Bubble Sort, Insertion Sort and Merge Sort to sort them. Finally I want to display the runtime in nanoseconds of each sorting algorithm. Is there a class in Java that allows me to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) to measure the time spent in your code. (Use the time difference between the start and end of the code under test.) Be aware, however, that the actual time measurement probably does not have nanosecond resolution.

You might want to look into a good Java benchmarking framework for measuring your code's performance. A general web search will turn up quite a few good candidates. Doing timing tests is not at all an easy thing to get right.